# List passed by ref - help me explain this behaviour

Tags: c#, list, pass-by-reference

Take a look at the following program:

```
class Test
{
    List<int> myList = new List<int>();

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        myList.Add(100);
        myList.Add(50);
        myList.Add(10);

        ChangeList(myList);

        foreach (int i in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeList(List<int> myList)
    {
        myList.Sort();

        List<int> myList2 = new List<int>();
        myList2.Add(3);
        myList2.Add(4);

        myList = myList2;
    }
}
```

I assumed `myList` would have passed by `ref`, and the output would

```
3
4
```

The list is indeed "passed by ref", but only the `sort` function takes effect. The following statement `myList = myList2;` has no effect.

So the output is in fact:

```
10
50
100
```

Can you help me explain this behavior? If indeed `myList` is not *passed-by-ref* (as it appears from `myList = myList2` not taking effect), how does `myList.Sort()` take effect?

I was assuming even that statement to not take effect and the output to be:

```
100
50
10
```

Comment: Just an observation (and I realize the problem has been simplified here), but it seems like it'd be best for `ChangeList` to return a `List<int>` rather than be a `void` if it's in fact creating a new list.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You are passing a *reference to the list*, but your **aren't** passing the list variable *by reference* - so when you call `ChangeList` the *value of the variable* (i.e. the reference - think "pointer") is copied - and changes to the *value of the parameter* inside `ChangeList` *aren't* seen by `TestMethod`.

try:

```
private void ChangeList(ref List<int> myList) {...}
...
ChangeList(ref myList);
```

This then passes *a reference to the local-variable* `myRef` (as declared in `TestMethod`); now, if you reassign the parameter inside `ChangeList` you are also reassigning the variable *inside* `TestMethod`.

Comment: Indeed I can do that, but I want to know how sort is taking effect

Comment: @Ngm - when you call `ChangeList`, **only the reference** is copied - it is the same object. If you change the object in some way, **everything** that has a reference to that object will see the change.

Answer (score 268):

Initially, it can be represented graphically as follow:

[image: Init states]

Then, the sort is applied `myList.Sort();`
[image: Sort collection]

Finally, when you did: `myList' = myList2`, you lost the one of the reference but not the original and the collection stayed sorted.

[image: Lost reference]

**If you use by reference (`ref`) then `myList'` and `myList` will become the same (only one reference).**

Note: I use `myList'` to represent the parameter that you use in `ChangeList` (because you gave the same name as the original)

Answer (score 23):

Here is an easy way to understand it

- Your List is an object created on heap. The variable `myList` is a
  reference to that object.
- **In C# you never pass objects, you pass their references by value.**
- When you access the list object via the passed reference in
  `ChangeList` (while sorting, for example) the original list is changed.
- The assignment on the `ChangeList` method is made to the value of the reference, hence no changes are done to the original list (still on the heap but not referenced on the method variable anymore).

Answer (score 13):

[This](https://web.archive.org/web/20170314184846/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(VS.71).aspx) link will help you in understanding pass by reference in C#.
Basically,when an object of reference type is passed by value to an method, only methods which are available on that object can modify the contents of object.

For example List.sort() method changes List contents but if you assign some other object to same variable, that assignment is local to that method. That is why myList remains unchanged.

If we pass object of reference type by using ref keyword then we can assign some other object to same variable and that changes entire object itself.

(Edit: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters) is the updated version of the documentation linked above.)

Answer (score 8):

C# just does a shallow copy when it passes by value unless the object in question executes `ICloneable` (which apparently the `List` class does not).

What this means is that it copies the `List` itself, but the references to the objects inside the list remain the same; that is, the pointers continue to reference the same objects as the original `List`.

If you change the values of the things your new `List` references, you change the original `List` also (since it is referencing the same objects).  However, you then change what `myList` references entirely, to a new `List`, and now only the original `List` is referencing those integers.

Read the *Passing Reference-Type Parameters* section from [this MSDN article on "Passing Parameters"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more information.

["How do I Clone a Generic List in C#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c) from StackOverflow talks about how to make a deep copy of a List.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `ref` keyword.

Look at the definitive reference [here](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html) to understand passing parameters.
To be specific, look at [this](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html#value), to understand the behavior of the code.

EDIT: `Sort` works on the same reference (that is passed by value) and hence the values are ordered. However, assigning a new instance to the parameter won't work because parameter is passed by value, unless you put `ref`.

Putting `ref` lets you change the pointer to the reference to a new instance of `List` in your case. Without `ref`, you can work on the existing parameter, but can't make it point to something else.

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with what everyone has said above. I have a different take on this code.
**Basically you're assigning the new list to the local variable myList not the global.**
if you change the signature of ChangeList(List myList) to private void ChangeList() you'll see the output of 3, 4.

Here's my reasoning...
Even though list is passed by reference, think of it as passing a pointer variable by value
When you call ChangeList(myList) you're passing the pointer to (Global)myList. Now this is stored in the (local)myList variable. So now your (local)myList and (global)myList are pointing to the same list.
Now you do a sort => it works because (local)myList is referencing the original (global)myList
Next you create a new list and assign the pointer to that your (local)myList. But as soon as the function exits the (local)myList variable is destroyed.
HTH

```
class Test
{
    List<int> myList = new List<int>();
    public void TestMethod()
    {

        myList.Add(100);
        myList.Add(50);
        myList.Add(10);

        ChangeList();

        foreach (int i in myList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

    private void ChangeList()
    {
        myList.Sort();

        List<int> myList2 = new List<int>();
        myList2.Add(3);
        myList2.Add(4);

        myList = myList2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts of memory allocated for an object of reference type. One in stack and one in heap. The part in stack (aka a pointer) contains reference to the part in heap - where the actual values are stored.

When ref keyword is not use, just a copy of part in stack is created and passed to the method - reference to same part in heap. Therefore if you change something in heap part, those change will stayed. If you change the copied pointer - by assign it to refer to other place in heap - it will not affect to origin pointer outside of the method.