# Coding style "ref" for List<T> or Collections

Tags: c#, coding-style

I have function that changes argument of List type (changes inner object state). For example:

```
    public void ChangeList<T>(List<T> source, T value)
    {
        //Actions
        source.Add(value);
        //Actions
    }
```

What is the function signature is better? And why?

First: `public void ChangeList<T>(List<T> source, T value)`

or

Second: `public void ChangeList<T>(ref List<T> source, T value)`

**Edit:** The question can be changed. How to explicitly specify that the function changes the state of the list? (except function name or ReadonlyCollection)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use ref and when it is not necessary in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/635915/when-to-use-ref-and-when-it-is-not-necessary-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Like Marc answered, using `ref` (or not using it) isn't a "coding style". A coding style is preferring 2 spaces instead of a 1 tab, or using `{ }` for single-line `if` statements. `ref` has a functional behavior and is used depending on the context of the method. Read and learn what `ref` does on MSDN and decide if you need it or not: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

Comment: Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311226/list-passed-by-ref-help-me-explain-this-behaviour The answer (graphical) below the actual marked one is better to understand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one. The second one screams "I don't know what `ref` means"; it is simply wrong here. This isn't even a style question, really. The only reason to use `ref` in this context is if the `ChangeList` method needed to *reassign the list* (returning a different list instance, rather than doing what the name suggests, and mutating the existing list). And in that scenario, I think a `return` would be better:

```
public List<T> TransformBasedOnList<T>(List<T> source, T value) { ... }
```

Comment: I'd question the use of the `return`, as there's a risk that someone using the method might incorrectly assume the list passed as a parameter would remain unchanged.

Comment: I mean "How to explicitly specify that the function changes the inner state of object?". For example, in C++ you may use 'const' or not.

Comment: @EvgeniyMironov and in C++, it is still a lie - you can cast around it, IIRC. I suggest you just document the method ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for your answers =)

Answer (score 0):

You should Use ref only when you are changing reference of List:
e.g.

```
public void ChangeList<T>(ref List<T> source, T value)
{
    //Actions
    source = new List<T>; // or initialize using API/DB call
    source.Add(value);
    //Actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, see this sample application that showcases the difference between passing an argument by `ref`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int val = 1;
    int val2 = 1;

    Add(ref val);
    Add(val2);
    Console.WriteLine("Add 44 to Refence of val: " + val);
    Console.WriteLine("Add 44 to i, not by ref:  " + val2);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void Add(ref int i)
{
    i += 44;
}

static void Add(int i)
{
    i += 44;
}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, when passing a value by `ref`, you change the value "outside" of the scope of the called method. The calling method is aware of these changes. Basically, the called method "has a reference to that variable's memory location" and that location has a value assigned. I do have a type-o in my console output, that should say `Add 44 to val2, not by ref:`

When you **don't** use `ref`, the change doesn't get "recognized" outside of the scope of the method that was called. Instead it's passed the *value* of the argument / parameter, the actual memory reference is disregarded and only the method's local value is changed.

Not a very good explanation, truthfully my vocabulary isn't spectacular in this matter (and I'd love it if someone could correct me!) but I think the example is simple enough and the screenshot clearly shows the differences.

Edit: Also, just re-linking MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

And pointing out this important note as well,

> Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed by reference.

A "reference type" is basically just a type that only refers to a memory location, so you could have 2 reference types that refer to the same object instance. A "value type" directly contain the actual value and you can't mess up one value type's value by modifying a different value type; they're two separate instances that just happen to have the same value. However, using `ref`, you can make value types behave in a fashion similar to reference types.

Think of it like saying, "Get the coat on the third hook"- that's a reference. You know where a coat is, it's reference. If you said, "Get my coat" you know exactly what coat (value) you're getting.