# Arrays passed by reference or by value

Tags: c#, arrays, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are arrays or lists passed by default by reference in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967402/are-arrays-or-lists-passed-by-default-by-reference-in-c)

I have read some contradicting posts on here about C# and whether arrays are passed by value or by reference. Could someone clarify whether C# arrays are passed by value or by reference?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967402/are-arrays-or-lists-passed-by-default-by-reference-in-c

Comment: See http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reference to the array is passed by value. This is the source of the confusion :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you change elements inside array, inside a function it will affect array outside of that function but it not means that it is passed by reference by default :).

You can see this for more clarification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szasx730(v=vs.71).aspx