# Decorating FileStream with custom Read() and Write() functionalities

Tags: c#, stream, decorator, filestream

I am trying to decorate the `Stream` class with a `CaesarStream` class, which basically applies Caesar cipher to both `Read` and `Write` operations. I've managed to override the `Write` method quite easily, but the `Read` is giving me a headache. From what I understand, I need to call the underlying `FileStream`'s `Read` method and somehow modify it, but how do I make it read the values while also adding a number to each byte, similar to what I did in the `Write()` method? This is harder for me, because `Read`'s return value is just the amount of bytes read, not the actual read items.

```
public class CaesarStream : Stream
{
    private int _offset;
    private FileStream _stream;

    public CaesarStream(FileStream stream, int offset)
    {
        _offset = offset;
        _stream = stream;
    }
    public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        //I imagine i need to call 
        //_stream.Read(array, offset, count);
        //and modify the array, but how do i make my stream return it afterwards?
        //I have no access to the underlying private FileStream fields so I'm clueless
    }
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        byte[] changedBytes = new byte[buffer.Length];

        int index = 0;
        foreach (byte b in buffer)
        {
            changedBytes[index] = (byte) (b + (byte) _offset);
            index++;
        }

        _stream.Write(changedBytes, offset, count);
    }
}
```

PS I know i should also check the amount of bytes read/written and keep reading/writing until it's finished, but I haven't gotten to that yet. I'd like to be done with the reading part first.

Comment: You just modify the `array` in the same(only by detracting the `_offset`) way you do it in the `Write` method. You don't need to return anything else then the return value of `base.Read`, because `array` is a reference  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967402/are-arrays-or-lists-passed-by-default-by-reference-in-c.

Comment: @Eugene Just to make sure I understand you correctly, I call the FileStream's Read and pass to it an array of shifted zeros, and it will read into it?

Comment: @Marchin You call `base.Read` with the arguments you receive, then you iterate over each element in the array (up to the returned by `base.Read` count) and decipher them in place. The caller will then have the already deciphered data in the `array` it passed to you.

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. It was actually simpler than I expected

Answer (score 2):

Following Eugene's advice I managed to make it work as intended, here's the code in case someone would like to see it:

```
public class CaesarStream : Stream
{
    private int _offset;
    private FileStream _stream;


    public CaesarStream(FileStream stream, int offset)
    {
        _offset = offset;
        _stream = stream;
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] array, int offset, int count)
    {
        int retValue = _stream.Read(array, offset, count);

        for (int a = 0; a < array.Length; a++)
        {
            array[a] = (byte) (array[a] - (byte) _offset);
        }

        return retValue;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        byte[] changedBytes = new byte[buffer.Length];

        int index = 0;
        foreach (byte b in buffer)
        {
            changedBytes[index] = (byte) (b + (byte) _offset);
            index++;
        }

        _stream.Write(changedBytes, offset, count);
    }
}
```

Comment: These methods should take offset and count into account. As they stand they modify the entire array.