# list<list<int>> assigning values using list[][] C#

Tags: c#, list, multidimensional-array

I was trying to use a `List<List<int>>` Code :

```
List<List<int>> list2D = new List<List<int>>();
List<int> NULLLIST = new List<int>();

NULLLIST.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 6));
list2D.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(NULLLIST, 6));

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        list2D[i][j] = (5 * (i-1)) + j;

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++, Console.WriteLine())
    for (int j = 1; j <= 5; j++)
        Console.Write(list2D[i][j].ToString() + ' ');

Console.ReadLine();
```

I thought the output would be like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

but the output was

```
21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25
```

I don't know what is wrong and how to get the first output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `NULLLIST` 5 times. If you want to use loops, you can use a loop to initialize the lists:

```
list2D.Add(new List<int>()); // (*)

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var NULLLIST = new List<int>();
    NULLLIST.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 6));
    list2D.Add(NULLLIST);
}
```

*Why have I added the line marked with `(*)`?*

Normally, lists index start at `0`, so an initial padding element is required. So, two additional advices:

- try to use 0-based indexes, otherwise its confusing
- try to use arrays, it'll get easier

Idea:

```
int[,] list2D = new int[5, 5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        list2D[i, j] = (5 * i) + (j + 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++, Console.WriteLine())
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        Console.Write(list2D[i, j].ToString() + ' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to avoid mixing *Linq* and *loops*, if you start generating `list2D` with *Linq* keep on doing it:

```
int lineCount = 5;
int colCount = 5;

var list2D = Enumerable
  .Range(0, lineCount)   // 5 lines
  .Select(line => Enumerable
     .Range(0, colCount) // 5 columns
     .Select(column => colCount * line + column + 1)
     .ToList())
  .ToList();
```

Test

```
string test = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list2D
  .Select(line => string.Join(" ", line)));

Console.WriteLine(test);
```

Outcome:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25
```

Answer (score 2):

The point is in this line: <sup>[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/967413/4519059)</sup>

```
list2D.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(NULLLIST, 6));
```

I think in above code we have 6 pointer to one clone of `NULLLIST`
in each iteration of `i` you are updating that clone of `NULLLIST` it means you have:

```
1 2 3 4 5  //=> NULLLIST clone: {1,2,3,4,5}
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

then

```
6 7 8 9 10  //=> NULLLIST clone : {6,7,8,9,10}
6 7 8 9 10 
6 7 8 9 10 
6 7 8 9 10 
6 7 8 9 10
```

and at last:

```
21 22 23 24 25  //=> NULLLIST clone: {21,22,23,24,25}
21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25
21 22 23 24 25
```

---

You can use this way:

```
var list2D = new List<List<int>>();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var row = new List<int>();
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        row.Add(5*i + j + 1);

    list2D.Add(row);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++, Console.WriteLine())
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        Console.Write($"{list2D[i][j],5}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list2D = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(i => 
                                         Enumerable.Range(i * 5 + 1, 5).ToList()).ToList();
```

or a bit shorter:

```
var list2D = new int[5].Select((_, i) => Enumerable.Range(i * 5 + 1, 5).ToList()).ToList();

foreach (var list in list2D) 
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", list));
```