# Keyword Ref required at sub-use of Ref?

Tags: c#, ref

I found this method at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17841639/6887468)

```
public static void RemoveAt<T>(ref T[] arr, int index)
{
    for (int a = index; a < arr.Length - 1; a++)
    {
        arr[a] = arr[a + 1];
    }
    Array.Resize(ref arr, arr.Length - 1);
}
```

Now I wanted to know if `ref` is required if it is used within a nested method? So could be the method also:

```
public static void RemoveAt<T>(T[] arr, int index) //ref removed
```

with the same functionality? I already tested it and it worked - but that means you could change reference without passing `Ref` Keyword. You just could do it in a sub method.

Comment: @FCin but if I resize the Array, I technically create a new one and the pointer needs to be changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are arrays or lists passed by default by reference in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967402/are-arrays-or-lists-passed-by-default-by-reference-in-c)

Comment: "I already tested it and it worked" - by "worked" do you mean "it compiles" or "the method behaves as it's meant to". I suspect you mean the first, not the second.

Comment: Yes, it is required if you want the change made by the sub-method to propagate out of the current method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but that means you could change reference without passing Ref Keyword. You just could do it in a sub method

That's not true. Although you could change the reference *within* your `RemoveAt`-method, that change won't affect the reference passed to it. You just throw the new (resized) instance away. When you want to change the *reference* to point to some other instance, your method should have the `ref`-keyword.

In other keywords your second code could also be written like this:

```
public static void RemoveAt<T>(arr, int index)
{
    for (int a = index; a < arr.Length - 1; a++)
    {
        arr[a] = arr[a + 1];
    }
    var reference = arr;
    Array.Resize(ref reference, arr.Length - 1);
}
```

While `reference` would of course change after calling `Array.Resize`, `arr` will stay the same. They reference completely different instances.

Comment: Anyone cares to explain the down?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality won't be the same. `Resize` can change the reference to `arr`, so in the first case you'd be changing an external reference of the caller, and without `ref` you'll only be changing the local method reference.

With ref:

```
var extArr = new object[100];

RemoveAt(ref extArr, 10); // The arr variable in this method is now the exact same physical
                          // variable as extArr.

// extArr is now a completely valid reference to the resized array, business as usual.
```

Without:

```
var extArr = new object[100];

RemoveAt(extArr , 10); // The copy of the reference (arr) is updated in this method 
                       //internally, but the local variable extArr is only copied and not modified

// extArr is now a reference to the old, not-resized array. 
// Note that the element is still "removed", overwritten in the for loop,
// but the resized copy of the array is lost and has no references to it.
```

Comment: `arr` will not be an invalid reference It will still be a perfectly valid reference to an 100 element array. You don't get invalid references in C#. That's part of what makes them references and code safe.