# C# Passing array by reference

Tags: c#, arrays, pass-by-reference

I know there are very similar questions but I need to know what's going on in this specific case. I wrote a function to reverse items of a multidimensional array along a specific dimension. To do this I convert the multidimensional array to a jagged array and than recursively find the array dimension where perform the reversal.

```
public static void Reverse(this Array array, int dimension, int start, int end)
{
    object[] jag = array.ToJaggedArray();

    if (!jag.ReverseAux(0, dimension, start, end))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dimension", dimension, "Dimension must be nonnegative and less than array dimensions number.");

    array = jag;
}
```

Now my problem is that when I run this method my input array has not been modified. Shouldn't an array be passed by reference? When I assign `array = jag` why it is correctly assigned inside the method but not outside?

For example:

```
// create 2D array of strings
string[,] ar = {{"00", "01", "02"},
                {"10", "11", "12"},
                {"20", "21", "22"}};
// reverse the first dimension (rows)
ar.Reverse(0, 0, 2);
// show the result
MessageBox.Show(ar.ToString(null, null));
```

The output is `{{00, 01, 02}, {10, 11, 12}, {20, 21, 22}}` that is exactly the original array. If I check the output in `Reverse` method

```
public static void Reverse(this Array array, int dimension, int start, int end)
{
    //...

    array = jag;
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(array.ToString(null, null));
}
```

this shows the correct reversed array `{{20, 21, 22}, {10, 11, 12}, {00, 01, 02}}`.

Shouldn't an array be passed by reference? Why after the local assignment my input array is referencing the orignal pointer and not the assigned? Should I use `ref` keyword for array argument? If yes is it possible to continue using this method as an extension of `Array` type?

Comment: Parameters are passed by value unless you use the `ref` or `out` modifiers. Extension methods don't support passing by reference however.

Comment: @Lee - There is also `in` modiier to pass by reference added in 7.3

Comment: @Shoter that won't help here neither.

Comment: The confusion here is because C# hides pointers from the users, unless you explicitly tell so, every param is passed by value. An array is a continuous amount of memory, the parameter that you receive is actually the pointer to where that memory starts. Updates to the array items (array[x]) are reflected to the user, but the updates to the pointer (array variable itself) are not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are arrays or lists passed by default by reference in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967402/are-arrays-or-lists-passed-by-default-by-reference-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All references/values in paramaters of function other than with **out** and **ref** modifiers can be considered as solely **local** variables (though, you still can change values inside referenced objects).

In C# we do such extension methods like this, so it looks like it is stateless extension method:

```
public static Array Reverse(this Array array, int dimension, int start, int end)
{
    object[] jag = array.ToJaggedArray();

    if (!jag.ReverseAux(0, dimension, start, end))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dimension", dimension, "Dimension must be nonnegative and less than array dimensions number.");

    return jag;
}

var output = input.Reverse(...);
```